# My friend's letter

Tags: riddle, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

*I received a letter from a friend yesterday, and thought I would share it here. Here's what it said:*

---

I hope you're keeping well. It was nice to hear from you the other day. I finally figured out your last puzzle by the way - is the answer `uggcf://jjj.tbbtyr.pb.hx/zncf/qve/H/X/P/b/q/r/f` ?

These lockdown days have made my usual hobbies a little trickier than normal; but hopefully we'll be back on the right path soon enough. I've put together an itinerary for next time we meet - please find it below - you know what to do with it:

```
\*>#+\_+>~*>#+\_
)^;*}*+
(&^~}>+
|"=*&;+
>["<+*
\[%,}~+
-%,*!*+
_+#%!:".
```

Oh yeah, also, you asked me for some book recommendations. I know it was, basically, 35 or 36 books you asked for; but that seems too many to read in one go so here's the ones I think you'll enjoy along with my ranking of them:

33 Violet Sepotho (the whole series is good!)
34 Barad-dûr and Orthanc
35 Candace and Toby
37 Psammead
38 Opo, Spray, Doris, Buzz and Tuffy
40 Kirsten Raymonde
41 Solomon Northup
42 Meg and Minnie
44 Sam Deker
45 Harry August
46 Dr. Siri Phaiboun
58 Kara Spencer, Flowers not Space
59 E.L. Pender
60 Unnamed Rabbi of Talmudic Legend, 1976
61 Natalie sends letters to Dan
62 Rose Gardner (It's the smallest I can find, but I wish it was smaller by half)
91 Milady de Winter
92 Ivor Orr
94 Tom Holt and the computer simulated Brothers Grimm
95 Shannon Molloy
124 Pamphylius and Julius, amongst many others
125 Chi-Yuen Ai-Ling
126 Professor William Waterman Sherman

Hopefully see you soon!

---

*Can you help me figure out my friend's book recommendations, and the itinerary - where I'm going, how far I'll be travelling and what I'm likely to be doing when I get there?*

Hints - some background about my friend

> My friend works at the post office (which is why he sends me letters instead of emails!), and he's always been obscurely basic in his approach to life. He changes hobbies regularly, but he tells me even though he's been coaching his friends in this one for a while, he's started expressing an interest in some alternatives; and I think I might be joining him as he starts down that track.

> My friend has always disliked the Romans, they're just not radical enough for him!

> My friend lives near Foxton Railway Station, England; and is often inspired by his local road network when setting cyphers and clues.

Comment: Feel free to post partial answers to help others along. I'm up for feedback afterwards too, if it's too hard/easy!

Comment: Would you like to clarify "Rose Gardner" further? There seem to be many options...

Comment: @Stiv hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Also, is #43 deliberately missing from the recommendation list?

Comment: @Stiv yes, it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Finally fully solved!**

Bear in mind throughout that ultimately our aim is to decode the block of symbols which is supposed to be an 'itinerary' for the next time the two characters in the story meet up. This means it will most likely work out to be a list with some meaning to the pair of them. Let's now work out what that might be...

First notice that the list of 'recommendations'...

> ...provides a set of clues (via character names, locations and plot points) to books that have a **number in the title**:
>
>  33 Violet Sepotho (the whole series is good!) = THE NO. **1** LADIES’ DETECTIVE AGENCY
>  34 Barad-dûr and Orthanc = THE **TWO** TOWERS
>  35 Candace and Toby = MISSING AT **17**
>  37 Psammead = **FIVE** CHILDREN AND IT
>  38 Opo, Spray, Doris, Buzz and Tuffy = **NINE** TRUE DOLPHIN STORIES
>  40 Kirsten Raymonde = STATION **ELEVEN**
>  41 Solomon Northup = **TWELVE** YEARS A SLAVE
>  42 Meg and Minnie = **TEN**
>  44 Sam Deker = THE **34TH** DEGREE
>  45 Harry August = THE FIRST **FIFTEEN** LIVES OF HARRY AUGUST
>  46 Dr. Siri Phaiboun = **THIRTY-THREE** TEETH
>  58 Kara Spencer, Flowers not Space = **TWENTY-SIX** ROSES
>  59 E.L. Pender = **TWENTY SEVEN** BONES
>  60 Unnamed Rabbi of Talmudic Legend, 1976 = THE RABBI AND THE **TWENTY-NINE** WITCHES
>  61 Natalie sends letters to Dan = **16** WAYS TO BREAK A HEART
>  62 Rose Gardner (It's the smallest I can find, but I wish it was smaller by half) = **TWENTY-EIGHT** AND A HALF WISHES
>  91 Milady de Winter = THE **THREE** MUSKETEERS
>  92 Ivor Orr = CATCH-**22**
>  94 Tom Holt and the computer simulated Brothers Grimm = SNOW WHITE AND THE **SEVEN** SAMURAI
>  95 Shannon Molloy = **FOURTEEN**
>  124 Pamphylius and Julius, amongst many others = **TWENTY THREE** TALES
>  125 Chi-Yuen Ai-Ling = TAU **ZERO**
>  126 Professor William Waterman Sherman = THE **TWENTY-ONE** BALLOONS

Note also that the numbers indicated as 'rankings' at the start of each row in this list...

> ...correspond to **[ASCII codes](https://www.ascii-code.com/)** for symbols:
>
> ```
>  33 !    34 "    35 #    37 %    38 &    40 (
>  41 )    42 *    44 ,    45 -    46 .    58 :
>  59 ;    60 <    61 =    62 >    91 [    92 \
>  94 ^    95 _   124 |   125 }   126 ~
> ```

What we have here then appears to be...

> ...some kind of **key** that can likely be used on the symbol-encoded 'itinerary', where each ASCII symbol corresponding to a book's 'ranking' is equivalent to the number found within the title of the book:
>
> ```
>  ! is  1    " is  2    # is 17    % is  5    & is  9    ( is 11
>  ) is 12    * is 10    , is 34    - is 15    . is 33    : is 26
>  ; is 27    < is 29    = is 16    > is 28    [ is  3    \ is 22
>  ^ is  7    _ is 14    | is 23    } is  0    ~ is 21
> ```

Applying this, then, to the encoded itinerary we see that all except one symbol (+) can be translated, resulting in the following (obviously further-encoded) message:

> 22/10/28/17 + 22/14 + 28/21/10/28/17 + 22/14
>  12/7/27/10/0/10 +
>  11/9/7/21/0/28 +
>  23/2/16/10/9/27 +
>  28/3/2/29 + 10
>  22/3/5/34/0/21 +
>  15/5/34/10/1/10 +
>  14 + 17/5/1/26/2/33

Next, we should note the remark within the puzzle: "*it was, basically, 35 or 36 books you asked for*"... This means we should...

> ...interpret the resulting characters using **[base-36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36)** (references to '*basically*' and '*36*'). In this base the numbers 0-35 are used to encode the digits 0-9 followed by the letters A-Z. This means 'A' is represented by '10', explaining one of the hints:
>
>  "*My friend lives near Foxton Railway Station, England; and is often inspired by his local road network when setting cyphers and clues.*"
>
>  ...since [the nearest major UK road](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Foxton/@52.1191925,0.0564674,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x2377c72f830c7eaf?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMpMO76-HrAhXQQEEAHYIvC0kQ_BIwE3oECBsQCA) to this railway station is the 'A10'.

Applying this newfound knowledge gives us the following translation:

> MASH+ME+SLASH+ME
>  C7RA0A+
>  B97L0S+
>  N2GA9R+
>  S32T+A
>  M35Y0L+
>  F5YA1A+
>  E+H51Q2X
>
>  The first line of this clearly forms legitimate words in English - 'MASH ME, SLASH ME' - suggesting this is some kind of instruction to be applied to the rows that follow.

What does this instruction mean?

> In my own head (and this may not be the OP's precise intention for their choice of words) 'MASH' implies rearranging, while 'SLASH' implies splitting something into two.

How do we apply it? Well, recall the thus-far unused section: *I finally figured out your last puzzle by the way - is the answer `uggcf://jjj.tbbtyr.pb.hx/zncf/qve/H/X/P/b/q/r/f` ?*

This is...

> ...a rot-13 encoded web address for "https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/U/K/C/o/d/e/s". Needless to say, this is *not* a genuine URL, but instead provides a nudge towards some combination of **maps** and **UK codes**. With the friend working at the post office (Hint 1), this is a definite nod towards [**UK postcodes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom).

In fact...

> ...each of the lines beneath the instruction appears to be a jumbled-up postcode, judging by their length and the ratio of number:letter characters. This would be fitting, considering that we seek a coded itinerary - a list of locations (through postcodes) would be a perfect fit for what we seek. The question is now *how to reorder these jumbles to produce the required postcodes*?
>
>  A systematic approach that produces valid-looking postcodes is to take first the characters in the odd-numbered positions, then those in the even-numbered positions. This produces the following strings:
>
>  CR0+7AA, B70+9LS, NG9+2AR, S2+3TA, M50+3YL, FY1+5AA, and EH12+5QX.
>
>  Interpreting the '+' characters as spaces<sup>*1*</sup> yields a set of locations that all have something in common - these are all nearby to **TRAM STOPS**:
>
>  CR0 7AA = Addiscombe Tram Stop, Croydon
>  B70 9LS = Dudley Street Guns Village Tram Stop, West Bromwich
>  NG9 2AR = Middle Street Tram Stop, Nottingham
>  S2 3TA = Arbourthorne Road Tram Stop, Sheffield
>  M50 3YL = Anchorage Tram Stop, Salford
>  FY1 5AA = Central Pier Tram Stop, Blackpool
>  EH12 5QX = Murrayfield Stadium Tram Stop, Edinburgh
>
>  In fact, if we exclude the Tyne and Wear Metro system up in Newcastle-upon-Tyne (which is more of a light railway), the seven towns and cities in this list have **the only tram networks in the UK** - perhaps it would not be farfetched to suggest (what with the travel-related references to 'coach', 'express' and 'track') that the two characters in this scenario are both **tram enthusiasts**!
>
>  <sup>*<sup>1</sup> EDIT: The plus symbols here didn't actually need to be converted into spaces if one of the hints in the puzzle had been interpreted in a specific way. In Google Maps (referenced in the rot-13'd hint), a specific postcode can be targeted by typing it at the end of the URL with a plus symbol in place of the space (e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/place/CR0+7AA).*</sup>

So what's their plan?

> As typical tram enthusiasts, they are planning the Holy Grail of tram enthusiasm: **a day in which they tour the UK specifically to ride on every single one of its official tram networks**. They will start in Croydon (south London) and work their way up the country, via West Bromwich, Nottingham, Sheffield, Salford and Blackpool (always moving northwards) until finally reaching Edinburgh, approximately 340 miles (550-ish kilometres) from their starting point as the crow flies.
>
>  What will they do there? Well, with their final destination being so close to **Murrayfield rugby stadium** I suggest they will most likely be heading up to watch a match! Though of course, Edinburgh (which is without doubt my favourite city in the world) holds so many other delights too. I hope they make the most of their time up there and explore it properly!

Comment: rot13(vf vg cbffvoyr gung 43 vf abg cerfrag orpnhfr + vf zrnag gb or vagrecergrq yvgrenyyl? V jbaqre nobhg gur crevbq ng gur raq gbb.)

Comment: say if you want some help :) I don't want to give anything away too soon

Comment: @JeremyDover Possible (and there is only that one full stop too...)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 That's fine. Give the community some time to reflect and add their opinions to this!

Comment: Quick thought: rot13(Gur svefg yvar vf 16 punenpgref ybat. Pbhyq gung or n pyhr gung fbzr fbeg bs urknqrpvzny pbairefvba vf vaibyirq?)

Comment: @JeremyDover Hmm, I feel like there would be more 'obvious' ways to clue that if it were important... I do wonder quite how "35 books" is relevant though - there may be something there...

Comment: A word of warning: on mobile phone devices I know that a sequence of numbers may be interpreted as a random phone number which is clearly unintentional. I recommend you separate the numbers with commas, not spaces.

Comment: Hey Stiv, there's a small error in your answer. On the second-to-last line, you did not replace the third character. Also third-to-last line, fourth character.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyDover I got so muddled up in 34's, 43's and 44's I'm not surprised a couple of wrong'uns slipped through...

Comment: rot13(Gur svefg guerr fcbvyre gntf unir gur cebprff evtug (nygubhtu vg zvtug unir orra rnfvre gb ercynpr gur obbx engvatf jvgu gur flzobyf, engure guna ercynpvat gur flzobyf jvgu gur obbx engvatf; vs lbh frr jung V zrna? Fnirf zvkvat hc nyy gubfr fvzvyne ahzoref). Gur ynfg fcbvyre gnt arrqf zber gubhtug)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I have reformatted my answer now for easier reading, as suggested. Still no further on just yet with the next steps...

Comment: @Stiv good stuff. I'm hoping it's not too hard. I think there are enough clues to figure it out, but if they're too obtuse I can try and edit to make it a bit clearer, or add hints...

Comment: @Stiv I've added a hint to give something to think about over the weekend

Comment: @Stiv added another hint

Comment: @simonalexander2005 The problem I'm having is I'm not at all sure what logical leap I'm supposed to perform to get to the next stage. Re the hints, rot13(Uvag 1 pyrneyl vaqvpngrf n genafcbeg pbaarpgvba - pbnpu, rkcerff, genpx... - Uvag 2 fhttrfgf fbzrguvat ahzrevp engure guna yrggre-onfrq... Uvag 3, abg gur sbttvrfg - V'ir fghqvrq gur znc, gurer'f n pbnpu qrcbg arneol, gurer'f n envy argjbex, gur N10, gur Z11, ohg V unir ab vqrn ubj gb yvax nal bs gurfr gb n pvcure. Bar gubhtug jnf genafyngvat gur ahzoref gb ebnqf naq frrvat jurer gurl tb sebz naq gb, ohg vg qbrfa'g nccrne gb yrnq naljurer...)

Comment: @Stiv ok, rot13(Gur znva pyhr sbe gur arkg fgrc vf va "V xabj vg jnf, *onfvpnyyl, 35 be 36* obbxf lbh nfxrq sbe". "Onfvpnyyl" vf fhccbfrq gb chg lbhe zvaq guvaxvat nobhg onfrf, juvpu vf jul V nyfb hfr gur jbeq n ybg ryfrjurer gbb. Vf gung rabhtu bs n uvag?)

Comment: rot13(N10 jnf gur vagraqrq pyhr sbe gur guveq uvag, ol gur jnl - nf va N = 10)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Okay, I've now got 4 words that look helpful - I'll see what I can work out how to use them along with the rest...

Comment: @Stiv I would keep the line breaks (and replace them with `/` after decoding)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Okay, reformatted accordingly, though still nothing jumping out at me. Is there a hint for this next stage already in the text that I haven't spotted?

Comment: rot13(Vg'f na vgvarenel, fb lbh xabj vg ersref gb ybpngvbaf, naq gurl'er va gur HX. Nyfb zl sevraq jbexf ng gur cbfg bssvpr. "ZNFU ZR" vf gur xrl vafgehpgvba; ohg vs gung'f gbb hapyrne V pna gel nqqvat na nqqvgvbany uvag)

Comment: @stiv rot13("PE1+7NN" naq "TL1+5NN" unir orra genafyngrq vapbeerpgyl. V hfrq uggcf://jjj.qpbqr.se/onfr-36-pvcure vs vg urycf.

Bgurejvfr lbh qb unir gur pbeerpg cbfgpbqrf)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Ugh, how did I do that?! Was sure I'd double/triple-checked (I did it all manually rather than with a translator). Right, thanks for picking up on those errors - let's see if I can wrap this one up for good now! :)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I believe I might finally have it now? Took me long enough, sorry!

Comment: @Stiv Excellent! Thank you for your perseverance with this one! I obviously didn't put enough clues in!! If you feel so inclined, I always value constructive feedback on how to improve. Also, regarding rot13('ZNFU ZR FYNFU ZR', V jnf npghnyyl vagraqvat gur cbfgpbqrf (jvgu + fvtaf) gb or chg vagb gur tbbtyr zncf hey (orgjrra gur sbejneq FYNFUrf) va beqre gb ivfhnyvfr gur ebhgr. "/H/X/P/b/q/r/f" vf rira 7 punenpgref, gur fnzr nf gur ahzore bs cbfgpbqrf; fb vg svgf va irel jryy)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Ah yes, of course - I see now why the pluses were in the puzzle! I'll add one final remark in my answer to include that information. Re feedback, I would say that in itself it's not a bad puzzle - it had several interesting steps to it, and each time I got stuck I was able to unstick myself (eventually, often with a nudge). However, the use of book titles for part of it when the rest of the puzzle had a different theme felt a bit out of place - for a long time I was look for further literary connections when it turned out that none existed... (cont.)

Comment: ...Also, it would have been a more natural solve had lots of your subsequent hints appeared somehow in the initial puzzle itself, so that the entire solution path was all self-contained (and I wouldn't have needed so many nudges!). The number of clues in itself was a good number (I don't think you needed more). I guess as well that you used some reference to come up with the postcodes required for the puzzle - I never found this, and some of the codes seemed more 'in the general area' than pinpoint bang-on, so the solution didn't jump out without further thought. Still, very much enjoyed it!

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! Actually I just spent some time on google maps trying to find postcodes that fitted; but it's hard to do. You're right about the books of course.I'm glad you enjoyed it